# On Mac M1 machine - Not able to run EF core Migrations Add ,Update in Asp.Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, macos, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have recently got a Mac M1, I have to build a Microservice based Web API application on  Asp.net Core using EF & SQL Server.

I added EntityFrameworkCore(5.0.11) through NuGet Package successfully. The sdk & runtime installed details on my Mac is:

```
.NET SDKs installed:
- 6.0.101
.NET runtimes installed:
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.1 
- Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.1
```

Firstly , I was not able to install SQL Server 2019 on Mac but after searching I found a solution for that by installing SQL Edge on Docker & connecting to Azure Data Studio and it's working fine.

Now the problem is I am not able to run EFcore migration add initial, Update Database through Entity Framework. I searched everywhere but whenever I am executing these command, I am getting following error:

```
Build started... Build succeeded. It was not possible to find any
compatible framework version The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App',
version '3.1.0' (arm64) was not found.
 - The following frameworks were found: 6.0.1 
You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework
and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
 - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=arm64&rid=osx.12-arm64.
```

I did install the above framework but that is x64. And still EF command are not working and I am not able to update the database.
Is there any solution for this? Does EFCore work on Mac M1 machines?

Comment: it's likely that the project has a `global.json` that needs to be updated

Answer (score 7):

The reason is that ef tool is not able to find the correct arch for now.
A workaround is to force ef tool to use the latest runtime found on your machine.

```
export DOTNET_ROLL_FORWARD=LatestMajor
```

export the above env var and run `dotnet ef xxx` again.

Comment: This works for me on the M1 mac project target framework .net5

Answer (score 6):

**Update**

This fixes the problem permanently:

```
dotnet tool uninstall dotnet-ef -g
dotnet tool install dotnet-ef -a arm64 -g
```

---

You can also install EF tool locally

CD to your source directory and do this:

```
dotnet new tool-manifest
dotnet tool install  dotnet-ef
```

In this way, it works with the .Net 5/6 arm64.

There's a bug in the arm64 version installer that references the x64 version of EF Core.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Solved this issue for me "Failed to load /usr/local/share/dotnet/host/fxr/8.0.2/libhostfxr.dylib".

Answer (score 0):

Try to install proper SDK version manually from this [link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the sdk version for your cli,.NET 5 and below installs in a different directory and from your output looks like you cli points to .NET 6. You should install the ef tools locally like so

```
dotnet new tool-manifest # if you are setting up this repo
dotnet tool install --local dotnet-ef --version 5.0.15
```

then,

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet ef migrations add initialCreate -s ../API -o Migrations
```

You can shorten the path by using this article https://dev.to/smiththe_4th/use-multiple-net-sdk-cli-commands-on-mac-m1-64j